# resizing web page on internet explorer using zoom css property

Tags: css, zooming, resize

I'm trying to scale my webpage which I made on 1680 x 1050 monitor to fit a 800 x 600 monitor. I am setting the style/css to "zoom: .7" which works great except that the scroll bar appears. When I use the Internet Explorer developer tools I am checking all the elements and there aren't any elements that are making the page overflow. However, when I check , there's a blue border around the entire window.. I have even tried setting the width of  but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried making a fluid layout instead of relying on absolute pixel values? A well-written layout should be able to scale naturally without resorting to full-page resizing tricks. After all, a lower resolution is normally paired with a smaller screen, so making the font smaller will only take you so far.

Comment: If I have to rely on absolute pixel values, is there another solution?

Comment: Most modern browsers support Media Queries: http://www.google.com/search?q=css+media+queries

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to get rid of the scrollbars would be to apply

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to the element with the `zoom` property. Since you don't know which element overflows, perhaps you have to try other elements, like wrappers, to see if one of them 'works'.
If this doesn't work: I'm intrigued about the blue border you describe. Things don't turn blue out of themselves... so perhaps you could post some code if `overflow` doesn't do it.